# SQL copy one column then paste it in a new column with all white space removed

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy one column in my database and paste it into another column with all white space removed.  I do not want to use export/import but a SQL query if this is possible.

Comment: Set the values in an existing column, or add another column entirely and set those values?

Comment: I am trying to copy a column named City to a new column named City2.  I want to turn San Diego (from column City) into SanDiego.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET City2 = REPLACE(City, ' ', '');
```

This will remove **all** whitespace. Leading spaces, trailing spaces, all spaces.

This will turn:

- "Rio De Janerio" into "RioDeJanerio"
- "Sandusky    " into "Sandusky"
- "      Orangeville" into "Orangeville"

Comment: The column I am copying is called City and the new column is City2.  So how would I copy City into City2 without losing the joining columns (I am not sure if this makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

If the whitespace is leading and trailing then use the TRIM function. If it all whitespaces beetween words, trailing and leading use the replace function that @p.campbell suggested

Comment: the white space is in between the words.  I am trying to turn San Diego into SanDiego.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new column `city2` using ALTER TABLE. And then run the following query:

```
update `table` set `city2` = replace(`city`, ' ', '');
```

However, the above is assuming that both columns are in the same table. If they are from different tables you may use JOINS in the update query. Let me know if that helps.